# unsupported gradle method instrumentTestCompile

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I have an unsupported gradle method instrumentTestCompile when including espresso in my Android project `gradle.build` on Android studio following Google instructions:
https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso#Espresso_Setup_Instructions.

gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
  instrumentTestCompile files('libs/espresso-1.1.jar',
          'libs/testrunner-1.1.jar',
          'libs/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')

  instrumentTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
          'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
          'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
          'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
          'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
}
```

Complete error:

```
Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: ‘instrumentTestCompile()’!
Possible causes could be:
– you are using Gradle version where the method is absent
– you didn’t apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
– or there is a mistake in a build script
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the response here:
http://android.amberfog.com/?p=894

`instrumentTestCompile()` was renamed to `androidTestCompile()` in the latest version of gradle plugin.

Comment: For documentation purpose as the answer was not found on SO.

Comment: What's the difference between that and testCompile?

Comment: It is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021331/confused-about-testcompile-and-androidtestcompile-in-android-gradle